# Testing of Nginx server block

Tags: curl, nginx

I have installed Nginx 1.12.0 on my laptop.

I have a simple Nginx server block as follows:

```
server {
    listen         80;
    server_name    myserver.com;

    location /hello {
       return 200 'OK';
    }
}
```

I want to test the working of this server block. 
One method I can think of is :

- insert the following in /etc/hosts.

  - `127.0.0.1        myserver.com`
- execute the following command. This will give the response "OK"

  - curl "myserver.com/hello"

Is there any other method without editing the /etc/hosts file? I mean is it possible using just a curl command (probably using some headers like x-forwarded-server or something) ?

Answer (score 3):

You should add "Host" to the request header to determine which server the request should be routed to. For example, you can do the following:

```sh
curl -H 'Host: myserver.com' localhost:80/hello
```

Answer (score 1):

The `server_name` directive used to identify virtual hosts, it is not used to set the binding. Since the `listen 80` directive makes NGINX serve requests on all IP addresses, including 127.0.0.1, you can use:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1/hello
```

or

```
curl http://localhost/hello
```

without `/etc/hosts` changes, the latter assuming that `127.0.0.1 localhost` is already in there by default.

Comment: I commented the server_name directive and tried with the curl command as you mentioned. Now it gives me Not Found response. Did I miss something?